# mydomain.com/info.php doesn't works but mydomain.com:8008/info.php works

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, port, php5

Sorry the title, but I don't know how to name this question.

I'm on a dedicated server on ubuntu 11.04. It runs with plesk 10.3.
I change the listen port of apache 80 -> 8008

When I go into my domain : http://www.bobcat.pro, the site doesn't work.
If I go on http://www.bobcat.pro:8008 ... it doesn't work.

If I take a file like an image, or a script like :

## doesn't work

- http://www.bobcat.pro/info.php
- http://www.bobcat.pro/img/logo_mail.jpg
- http://www.bobcat.pro/mails/fr/account.html

## works

- http://www.bobcat.pro:8008/info.php
- http://www.bobcat.pro:8008/img/logo_mail.jpg
- http://www.bobcat.pro:8008/mails/fr/account.html

Question : How can I tell "http://www.bobcat.pro -> http://www.bobcat.pro:8008?

With rule nat? (iptables?)

Sincerely

Comment: I can't help you on how to fix it, but this is entirely expected. http://www.mysite.com is simply shorthand for www.mysite.com:80. Why? Because, port 80 is the standard HTTP port that all browsers in the world will look at. Why would you want to change your port from that?

Comment: Because I need to install Varnish, an http accelerator.

Comment: Fair enough - that bit's beyond me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run:

> iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

This will redirect everything on 80 to 8080

Comment: +1 but `-I` may be better.